# Missing signal names in Lattice Diamond

Tags: verilog, fpga, lattice-diamond

I have a Lattice Diamond project for an SPI multiplexer, which has the following module definition:

```
module spimux
(
input bmck,
input bssel,
input bmosi,
output bmiso,
input[3:0] a,
output[13:0] mck,
output[13:0] ssel,
output[13:0] mosi,
input[13:0] miso,
output reg[7:0] LED
);

OutputMux bmiso_mux (
    .clk(osc_clk),
    .out(bmiso),
    .a(a),
    .in(miso)
    );

// the idea here is that on each rising clock edge, the module will take
// the 4-bit address a and then set *one* of the 14 bits in "in".  One
// problem I see is that I don't prevent an invalid address of 0b1111 or
// 0b1110 from getting used.
module OutputMux
(
input clk,
output reg out,
input[3:0] a,
input[13:0] in
);

reg mask;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    // I tried this and it didn't help my situation
    //out <= (in & (14'b1 << a));
    // so I tried to assign to a temp variable and then do the bitmasking.. no change.
    mask = 14'b1 << a;
    out <= (in[13:0] & mask);
end

endmodule

endmodule
```

When I go into the Spreadsheet View to assign my pins, not all of them show up in the Signal Name droplist.  For example, it looks like this:

[image]

You'll see that miso[0] is in there as an Input Port, but all of the other 13 miso bits are not.  In addition, bmck, bssel, and bmosi are missing.  They have not yet been assigned to any other pins, so can anyone explain why they would not be there?

Comment: How do you drive `LED` in your `spimux` module?

Comment: @Qiu thanks, I just checked that.  Turns out I had a typo and was only driving half of the LEDs!

Comment: I'm going to change this question because I have another issue.

Comment: @Qiu based on the solution to my previous problem, is it fair to assume that the missing signal names are due to incorrect assignments in my other modules?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that some of your logic was simply synthesised away.

Comment: I'll add more code shortly.

Comment: It dawned on me that I should look for a tool to make testing Verilog easier for the newbies (i.e. me).  I found http://www.compileonline.com/compile_verilog_online.php, which is actually very useful for me to test out my bitmasking and shifting.  There is definitely a bug in my logic due to my lack of understanding of Verilog syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Qiu for getting me going in the right general direction.  I should have guessed that the signal name list is generated after compiling the Verilog code, so if the output/input isn't getting used, you won't need to map it to a pin.

Using compileonline.com, I was able to quickly iterate over my Verilog logic statements and figure out where the problem came from.  For miso, I was able to make them appear by changing my `always` block to look like this:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    out = (in[13:0] & (14'b1 << a)) > 0;
end
```

The idea here is really simple -- out of all of the MISO inputs entering the FPGA, we only want to look at the one coming from the SPI device that is currently selected (identified by address `a`).  We just need to set `out` to the value of the bit identified by `a`.  After masking, the value is going to be 0 or !0, so we just write this to `out`.

I wanted to use a reduction operator, but the online compiler didn't seem to work with this notation, so I just compared to 0 instead, which seems to work.  I still have to test this on hardware.